# nbastatR not working in RStudio build 353

Tags: r, r-package

Whenever I try to run the code `install.packages("nbastatR")` the following error pops up:

```
Installing package into ‘AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘nbastatR’ is not available for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at:
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages
```

I tried downloading from the Github repos through:

```
install.packages('devtools', lib='~/R/lib')
devtools::install_github('abresler/nbastatR')
```

But still no success.

```
Error:
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘nbastatR’ is not available for this version of R
```

Comment: You need to update R to the latest version (4.2.2)

Comment: Already done that still it shows the same error

Comment: Hey did you find any solution? I am getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

```
devtools::install_github("abresler/nbastatR", force = TRUE)
```

Comment: I don't see why setting `force=TRUE` would help.  Can you explain?

Comment: The force parameter is typically used when reinstalling packages to override any conflicts or errors that might occur. However, if you are installing the package for the first time, there is no need to use force = TRUE.

Comment: But that's not what the documentation says it does! ("Force installation, even if the remote state has not changed since the previous install" - i.e., the function checks the github commit hash and (if `force = FALSE`) skips the re-install if it hasn't changed. It **doesn't** (AFAICS) "override any conflicts or errors that might occur" ...